# the relation between $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ when $X$ an $Y$ are dependent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have two random variables $X$ an $Y$ that are dependent. It seems to me that $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ the $\sigma$-algebras generated by $X$ and $Y$ respectively are somehow connected, I just don't know how :/

Is my intuition right? Thank you for your time :)

Comment: This isn't a complete answer but I wouldn't expect $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ to be related as sets just because $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. This is because $\sigma(X), \sigma(Y)$ don't depend on your choice of probability measure whilst whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are dependent does so you should be able to at least find examples where one choice of measure makes $X$ and $Y$ independent whilst another makes them dependent.

Comment: @nobody, I was thinking about the measurability as a kind of relation, for instance, suppose in this example of dependent random variables that  $P(X(t)=\alpha|\sigma(Y(s)),s\leq t)=f_{\alpha}(Y(t))$, can we say in this case that $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable based on the fact that they are related by such expression ?!

Comment: My point was exactly that $X$ and $Y$ being dependent random variables shouldn't tell you $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable because $\sigma(Y)$-measurability isn't at all related to the choice of probability measure. However you now seem to be talking about processes rather than single random variables so you should decide what you want to ask about and clarify.

Comment: @nobody, yes, you're right I should clarify, I m asking now about stochastic processes that are dependent, will that change a lot in my question?

Comment: I still think your question needs further clarification. For example, usually independence of two processes means independence of all pairs of vectors of the form $(X_{t_1}, \dots, X_{t_n}),(Y_{t_1}, \dots, Y_{t_n})$. However in your previous comment you instead want to define dependence as the conditional expectation of a particular event being measurable with respect to a smaller than usual $\sigma$-algebra. It's not clear to me why these should be similar things, although maybe they and someone else will understand better than I do.